# Parsing Strings in Bash w/out a Delimiter

Tags: bash, parsing, bc

I've got a piece of a script I'm trying to figure out, so maybe its a simple question for someone more experienced out there.

Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "obase=2;$1" | bc
```

Used like:

```
$./script 12
```

Outputs:

```
1100
```

My question is, **how can I parse this 4 digit number into separate digits?** *(to then delimit with cut -d ' ' and input those into an array...)*

I'd like to be able to get the following output:

```
1 1 0 0
```

Is this even possible in BASH?  I know its easier with other languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can use `sed`

```
echo "obase=2;$1" | bc | sed 's/./& /g'
```

or if you prefer longer form:

```
echo "obase=2;$1" | bc | sed 's/\(.\)/\1 /g'
```

if your `sed` supports `-r`

```
echo "obase=2;$1" | bc | sed -r 's/(.)/\1 /g'
```

Comment: Wow dude; nice.  I had even come across that sed syntax and not realized it was the answer.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To print individual digits from a string you can use `fold`:

```
s=1100
fold -w1 <<< "$s"
1
1
0
0
```

**To create an array:**

```
arr=( $(fold -w1 <<< "$s") )

set|grep arr
arr=([0]="1" [1]="1" [2]="0" [3]="0")
```

Comment: I'd never even heard of fold; I've have to check it out. Thanks!

Comment: Your array syntax is much easier to user to accomplish what I needed also.  I am trying to learn these better, and arr is pretty handy.

Comment: Yes no doubt it is cleaner syntax to use arrays like this.

Comment: Can you help me understand how set|grep arr is calling the values of that array out?

Comment: `set|grep arr` is there just to display the content of array. You can call `set` in shell to print all the variables.